# Wind turbines or tidal power stations incorporating elements of origami or reconfigurable materials: is innovation possible from physics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, applied-physics, renewable-energy

If I refer well (I'm not a physicist) one of the oldest uses/applications of renewable energy is to try to exploit the wind and tides by means of designs of machines: windmills and water wheels. Today this technology has provided us with modern wind turbines and tidal energy (I refer the articles from  Wikipedia entitled [*Wind turbine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_turbine) and [*Tidal power*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_power)). I believe that the main subjects about this use of energy are the principle of conservation of energy as a general framework, and the importance of Bernoulli's principle and Venturi effect in fluid dynamics in the design of certain components of our machine: the blades and/or the turbine tunnel.

In recent decades, technologies are arising around origami and the known as reconfigurable materials. With the word origami I don't understand the folding of pieces of paper, I understand the creation of materials and structures that exploit some origami design (I know some of these from videos that I've seen). Thus we mean from rigid to flexible materials that incorporate elements of origami designs or reconfigurable materials.

> **Question.** I wondered if it is possible to innovate in the field of the mentioned renewable energies, wind energy or tidal energy, incorporating some design elements from origami or from reconfigurable materials. Is it possible? **Many thanks.**

I don't know if my question is maybe *yes* because one can to think that using creativity one can to improve the designs of for example a Savonius wind turbine or for example the design of some element of a tidal power station, by incorporation of some element from origami or reconfigurable materials in those designs. On the other hand maybe I'm naive and the modern designs of wind turbines and tidal power stations are virtually perfect.

I don't know if this specific question is in the literature, if this is the case I'm not asking for a specific design or patent, I'm asking if you as a physicist can elucidate if it is a good idea providing me with a small overview about the physics that we can exploit in such hypothetical cases or a concise explanation about a design/draft of your full creation if it is possible/legitimate. If there are articles from the literature feel free to refer these answering my question as a reference request and I try to search and read about it from the literature.

Comment: Just to provide an idea about what I mean about origami and reconfigurable materials I add that the  videos that I've seen about origami and reconfigurable materials are in YouTube, for example to illustrate a sample of these I refer the video with title *Paper Tubes Make Stiff Origami Structures* from the official channel **Georgia Tech** (at date December 1st, 2015), and from the official channel **Harvard John A. Paulson School of Engineering and Applied Sciences** the video entitled *Reconfigurable Materials* (date January 18th, 2017).

Comment: I hope that my question is suitable and good for the site Physics Stack Exchange, in oher case feel free to add your feedback in comments about the post.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not really suitable for Physics.SE. Almost certainly it _is_ possible to make origami-inspired innovation in turbine design, but whether this is actually _useful_ is much more of an engineering question, rather than a physics one. And anyway it's too broad a question for StackExchange.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback, many thanks, and thanks to the user who edited. I'm going to wait, I've asked a few questions and I trying to create a good account in this site. If there is more feedback about the question maybe isn't suitable I should delete the question in next days. I think that maybe can be some interesting issue of physics about my question, but I will not insist @leftaroundabout . If I can do a comparison there is applications of origami for solar power, see the article *Solar Power, Origami-Style* (date Aug. 14, 2014) from the web site of the **NASA** by Elizabeth Landau.